# Web API can't handle parameter I didn't know I was sending?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

So, my shiny new "Single Page Application" is crapping itself because of a 500 error that *seems* to be caused by the following API call: `/api/fuel/?_=123123123123`. This is pretty surprising to me because I can't imagine why the application would be making an API call like that to begin with; there's no such parameter anywhere on my controller, and I certainly don't advise anyone to ask for a URL of that form.

The error occurs when the page is loading up its viewmodel. It's supposed to be loading items from a database and shunting them through an ajax call as JSON back to Knockout.js to get stuck into some HTML somewhere; there's a *lot* of code involve and I wrote almost none of it, so...

Has anyone seen this before? Does anyone know where this ridiculously long number is coming from and why it's getting tacked onto my URLs? Is this even the droid I'm looking for?

Update:

I cracked open Fiddler and it *looks* like the problem may be A) unrelated to the parameter getting passed (is that a session ID or a validation token or some crap like that?). The 500 response I'm getting also includes some gobbledygook about how they want only parameterless constructors. Looks like I may need to take another look at my models?

Update 2:

Ok, maybe you guys knew this was coming, but I can't believe what fixed this problem: Apparently, Web API doesn't like for you to .Select() from an IOrderedQueryable (or something like that); I added .AsEnumerable() after the .OrderByDescending() and suddenly everything is peachy.

```
return db.FuelItems
    .Where(f => 
        f.UserId == cachedUserId
        //&& f.Date >= startDate 
        //&& f.Date < endDate)
        )
    .OrderByDescending(f => f.Date)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(f => new FuelItemDto(f));
```

Comment: Without seeing the ajax query it's hard to say what's causing this issue. What parameters does your FuelController's Get method expect?

Comment: None. (Although there are two GET methods--is that a problem in itself? The second one is looking for an ID, but the first one doesn't want anything at all.)

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: I'll post any specific code you like, but this is one of the new MVC templates and we're talking about... Well, about a thousand lines, total?

Comment: @archer884 No, that should not be a problem. My best guess is that whoever developed the JavaScript code is not building the correct URL to your API method. Maybe a quick Ctrl+F in the js code for anything with "$.ajax" might be a good place to start.

Comment: Are you always seeing `/api/fuel/?_=123123123123`, or does the number change?

Comment: The number changes. Still very curious what it is, but it doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: That would be the Entity Framework throwing an error, not Web API, I believe. EF has to translate the C# code into a SQL command, but using a constructor hides code and EF doesn't know what to do. See http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/20/avoiding-notsupportedexception-with-iqueryable.aspx for more details.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out, but it's not related to the question I originally asked, which Joel answered very well below. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_=....` is added by an ajax call to prevent the response from being cached.  The numeric part is a time stamp (in milliseconds), so it always changes. The assumption is that `_` is never going to be a real parameter in your query string, so it will not affect your request. However, it guarantees that the query string is always different, which prevents it from being cached by the browser.

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, section about *cache* option.